# mysql left, sort limit 1

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы (`orders`, `chat`) где `order_id = chat_id`. Как при запросе Select выбрать в сводной таблице только последнюю запись (отсортировать по полю `date_time`) из таблицы `chat`, с учетом того что что в таблице chat может присутствовать множество значений с одинаковым `chat_id`?

Выполняю запрос вида:

```
SELECT o.Name, c.chat_id
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN chat c
     ON o.order_id=c.chat_id
```

но выводит множество значений.

---

limit 1 не подходит так как он полностью ограничивает запрос SELECT а мне необходимо чтобы из таблицы orders выбирались все значения а из таблицы chat только последние значения. Т.Е. для каждого отдельного значения o.order_id получить отсортированное по дате последнее значение из таблицы chat

Comment: А где в вашем запросе limit и order by ?

Comment: Компьютер выполняет не то что ты хочешь, он делает то что ты пишешь

Comment: В общем добавьте `order by date_time desc limit 1`.

Comment: Укажите схему данных. У вас путаница с полями в вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

Указанный запрос в целом не соответствует постановке вопроса. Так как из присоединенной таблицы выбирается поле, по которому выполняется JOIN. Поставленный вопрос решается запросом вообще без JOIN:

```
SELECT o.Name, o.order_id FROM Orders o
```

Могу предположить, что в вопросе закралась ошибка, и в выборке нужен вовсе не `chat.chat_id`, а, например, `chat.id`. Тогда вопрос имеет смысл.

В MySQL это доступно только с использованием подзапроса (см. "Оконные Функции" в других БД) или путем хитрых JOIN'ов.

Однако, в случае, когда идентификаторы присоединенной таблицы заполняются автоинкрементом и сортировка по дате создания аналогична сортировке по идентификатору (например, выбрать последний из присоединенной таблицы), для вывода идентификаторов проще всего использовать группировку:

```
SELECT o.name, max(c.id) 
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN chat c ON c.order_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

Похожие запросы на англоязычном ресурсе:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626493/left-join-only-first-row

Comment: По-моему у Вас вот тут "c.order_id = c.id" ошибка ...

Comment: @nobody спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
select o.*
from orders o left join chats c
     on o.order_id = c.chat_id
     inner join (select chat_id, max(date_time) as maxi
                 from chats
                 group by chat_id) ma
           on c.chat_id = ma.chat_id and c.date_time = ma.maxi
```

Если в таблице нет других неважных полей, можно так:

```
select o.*
from orders o left join 
                (select chat_id, max(date_time) as maxi
                 from chats
                 group by chat_id) ma
           on o.order_id = ma.chat_id
```